# Search function calls in code

Tags: php, regex, bash, tokenize

I have a php project which needs upgrading from php 5.3 to php 5.6(and eventually, to php7), and from what I see in the PHP docs, the /e modifier for preg_replace is deprecated, and is to be removed, and I have to search all of its occurences and remove them(and replace them with something else, such as preg_replace_callback).

The problem is that there are lots of calls to preg_replace(around 2100 calls), and it would take a lot of time to check each of them manually, and I would like to create a script(either a php script or a bash script) which searches for all the preg_replace calls which use the specified modifier. I have searched online, and I found that this should be done either with a regex expression or with tokenizer. I have tried, but I have not managed to create a script which does just that(mainly because I have not really used any of the two functionalities mentioned, and am not proficient in any of them).

I was wondering if there is any easier way to do this, or if anyone could help me in creating a script which searches the entire codebase and outputs the required calls.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am sorry, an example of what? And no, the project is using an in-house built framework, which uses a few thousands of php files.

Comment: an example of how `preg_replace` is present..is it `preg_replace("/../e", $subst, $str);` or the regex is defined in some variable?

Comment: Ah. I'm sory. I have looked over the code, and all of the calls look something like this: `preg_replace( '/[^a-z0-9-_,]/i', '', $variable)` or `preg_replace(array('/ /', '/\./', '/\//', '/-/', '/\(/', '/\)/'), array('', '', '', '', '', ''), $number)`. So the regex is inside the function call, not in another variable.

Comment: are these only two possibilities because I think there can be many more combination?

Comment: From what I can gather, all of the calls look similar to these two. I haven't seen any calls with the regex inside variables, or anything like that. Here are some other examples of usage: `preg_replace('![e\s]+!', '', $match[1])`, `preg_replace('#(/\./(\./)*)|/{2,}#', '/', $_path)`, `preg_replace( '/^SELECT(.*)FROM/s','SELECT '.implode( ',', $id ).' FROM', $c['query'] )`

Comment: I don't see any `/e` modifier in your sample code.

Comment: Here is an example that uses the /e modifier: `preg_replace("/([a-z]*)/e", "strtoupper('\\1')", $kunden)`

Comment: Replacing the `preg_replace` and modifier can be done with a simple sed command, but extracting the second argument to make it a callback function might be a bit more tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your code editor's find and replace:

1. Do a backup of your code (if you don't use git or something)
2. Use the Find in Folder ( or similar ) option
3. Check the Regular Expression (or similar) option when searching
4. Use a simple regex like `preg_replace*?\/e`
5. Replace the occurences one by one
6. Move your code in PHP 5.6 environment and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be working. I wouldn't have thought that the answer would be so simple.